# Two different conventions of cofiber sequences?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of pointed spaces (with basepoints denoted by $*$). Denote $Cf$ to be the (reduced) mapping cone
$$Cf = ((X \times I) \sqcup Y) / ((x,0) \sim f(x) \cup X \times \{1\} \cup \{*\} \times I)$$
Let $i: Y \to Cf$ be the canonical map $y \mapsto [y]$. Now glue $Cf$ with the (reduced) cone $CY = Y \times I / (Y \times \{1\} \cup \{*\} \times I)$. It turns out the gluing gives the (reduced) suspension $\Sigma X$. Thus, we get a canonical map $\pi: Cf \to \Sigma X$. Now we can apply the functor $\Sigma^n$ to the sequence $X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{i} Cf \xrightarrow{\pi} \Sigma X$ and attaching them gives the sequence
$$X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{i} Cf \xrightarrow{\pi} \Sigma X \xrightarrow{\Sigma f} \Sigma Y \xrightarrow{\Sigma i} \Sigma Cf \xrightarrow{\Sigma \pi} \Sigma^2 X \xrightarrow{\Sigma^2 f} \Sigma^2 Y \xrightarrow{\Sigma^2 i} \Sigma^2 Cf \to \cdots$$
In McCleary's *A User's Guide to Spectral Sequence* (p.97), this is called the Barratt-Puppe sequence (or some call it the cofiber sequence generated by $f$). However, in May's *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology* (p.59), a cofiber sequence generated by $f$ is the sequence
$$X \xrightarrow{f} Y \xrightarrow{i} Cf \xrightarrow{\pi} \Sigma X \xrightarrow{-\Sigma f} \Sigma Y \xrightarrow{-\Sigma i} \Sigma Cf \xrightarrow{-\Sigma \pi} \Sigma^2 X \xrightarrow{-\Sigma^2 f} \Sigma^2 Y \xrightarrow{-\Sigma^2 i} \Sigma^2 Cf \to \cdots$$
where $-\Sigma f: \Sigma X \to \Sigma Y$ is the map $x \wedge t \mapsto x \wedge (1-t)$. (Here we identify $\Sigma X$ with the smash product $X \wedge S^1$ with $S^1 = I/\{0,1\}$.)

The first construction makes complete sense, as it simply apply the suspension functor and stick things together. However, what's the point of defining a cofiber sequence in the second way, where you keep "inverting" the $S^1$-coordinate everytime you "go up one level"?

Comment: The $-1$ signs turn up naturally when you actually do the construction. They come about because because you have to interchange the suspension coordinates with the coordinate in the mapping cylinder (the map $S^1\wedge S^1\rightarrow S^1\wedge S^1$, $x\wedge y\mapsto y\wedge x$ has degree $-1$). Thus you have the bottom sequence. Now map it to the top sequence by a family of maps of degree $\pm1$. This is an `equivalence' of sequences, and for this reason both give you the same exact sequence of sets/groups.

Comment: For a discussion of examples where the sign matters, see this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5901/do-the-signs-in-puppe-sequences-matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really important whether one uses $\Sigma$ or $-\Sigma$. The purpose of the cofiber sequence is to get an induced long exact sequence of homotopy sets $[-;Z]$ as in May's theorem on p. 59. If you replace $\Sigma \phi$ by $-\Sigma \phi$, you change the sign of the induced homomorphism $[\Sigma X,Z] \to [\Sigma Y,Z]$, but this does not affect exactness since images and kernels are preserved under such a change of sign.

I think May's definition has only technical reasons in his proof of the theorem. In the diagram on the top of p. 60 he uses the "suspension coordinate switch map" $\tau$ which is homotopic to $-id$. The right square commutes, thus the square in which we replace $\tau$ by $id$ and $\pi(\Sigma f)$ by $\pi(-\Sigma f)$ commutes up to homotopy. But in fact this is not really needed, commutativity up to sign would be sufficient.